# Lead Kanban View - missing status

Tags: lightning

We are using lightning and the kanban views,

When looking at the lead Kanban view i cannot see the lead status 'Qualified'

How do i show this on the Kanban view?

Comment: Is you "Qualified" the equivalent to "Converted". If that's so, you can't display converted lead in list view. It's not even a issue related to Lightning. Same behaviour in Salesforce Classic

Comment: Hi - no we have it as as an option in lead status - drop down field. It can be Qualified but not converted